# Using mvn war plugin, how to change the final war file permissions

Tags: maven

I have an existing pom.xml structure, using packaging=war and maven-war-plugin version 2.4.  My deploy phase, with goal 'war', appropriately renames my war to my desired file name, and even pushes it out to a given outputDirectory.  What I'm trying to do is set the final war file's permissions to 0775, rather than 0755.  (Use case: when I copy to the output directory, it appears to retain the permissions of the created war.)

The "obvious" attempt was to add fileMode to my configuration block...  appears to be ignored, unfortunately.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-copies-warfile</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>widgets</warName>
                        <outputDirectory>${webapps-dir}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Another attempt: settings.xml includes a filePermissions setting, per server to which you'd deploy.  This is unfortunately only a local build issue, so this doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: I would suggest to use something different for copying and changing the permissions for example maven-assembly-plugin with an dir format.